# Why does outside of shrimp stay frozen in refrigerator?

Tags: thermodynamics

Most cooked commercial shrimp come frozen and either get thawed out by the supermarket or by the customer. The shrimp are frozen solid and have to be immersed in water for about 30 minutes before they completely thaw. The problem with this approach is that the shrimp becomes waterlogged.

Accordingly, I followed a suggestion to leave the shrimp in the refrigerator overnight. My refrigerator is at about 35-40 degrees Farenheit. However, when I did this I found that the outer skin of the shrimp remained frozen, even if it was left in the refrigerator for over 3 days. The inner part became thawed. Why is this?

Comment: Might be a better question for the [Seasoned Advice SE](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @StephenG I think this is a better question for physics SE :) Not that I can guess the answer already...